# Loading modal while page is loading and close after done loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, bootstrap-modal

I there a way to load a modal while page is loading and close it when it is done loading?

For example, when I click a link:

```
<a href="localhost:3000/users">Stackoverflow</a>
```

the browser will load and at the same time modal will open. And if browser done loading the modal will close as well.

How can I possibly do it?

Comment: I don't think this will be possible. The modal has to be a part of the page, so it can not be displayed when the page is not loaded.

Comment: This is pointless feature. You can't implement it without workarounds, while if use workarounds page loading will take x2 time

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "Open Modal", your_path, :remote => true, :class => 'btn btn-default',  data: {toggle: 'modal', target: "#myLoadingModal" }%>
```

And then on document ready in your file.js.erb that is triggered when you're using remote: true on the link, this would close said modal when the document has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myLoadingModal').modal('hide');
});
```